# creating and upgrading data base in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am playing with SQLite and android.  So far my app has two activities..

a main activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class HomeFavesActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "HomeFavesCatovoty";
    SQLiteDatabase lcDB;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.v(TAG, "CREATED");

        DataBaseManager db = new DataBaseManager(this);
        db.getWritableDatabase();


    }
}
```

and a dataBaseManager class:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DataBaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String TAG = "DataBaseManager";
    static final String dbName ="LCInstore";

    static final String allIcons = "Icons";
    static final String homeIcons = "HomeScreenIcons";

    static final String colIconID = "IconID";
    static final String colID = "ID";
    static final String colImage = "IconImage";
    static final String colLabel = "IconLabel";
    static final String colName = "IconName";

    public DataBaseManager(Context context) {
        super(context, dbName, null, 4); // starting value is 1 must change on upgrades
        Log.v(TAG, "Initaited");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v(TAG, "on create called");
        // Create Icon Table if does not exist
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ allIcons +"" +
                "("+colIconID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                    colName + " TEXT," +
                    colImage + " TEXT," +
                    colLabel + "TEXT)");

        // Create HomeScreen Icons Table if does not exist
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST " + homeIcons+"" +
                "("+colID+" INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ("+colID+") REFERENCES " +
                        ""+allIcons+" ("+colIconID+"));");

         InsertIcons(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v(TAG, "on upgrade called");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+allIcons);
        InsertIcons(db);

    }

    private void InsertIcons(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
           cv.put(colIconID, 1);
           cv.put(colName, "Icon1");
           cv.put(colImage, "icon_one");
           cv.put(colLabel, "ONE");
           db.insert(allIcons, colIconID, cv);

           cv.put(colIconID, 2);
           cv.put(colName, "Icon2");
           cv.put(colImage, "icon_two");
           cv.put(colLabel, "TWO");
           db.insert(allIcons, colIconID, cv);

           cv.put(colIconID, 3);
           cv.put(colName, "Icon3");
           cv.put(colImage, "icon_three");
           cv.put(colLabel, "THREE");
           db.insert(allIcons, colIconID, cv);

           db.close();
    }

    public void AddHomeScreenIcon(int id){

       SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

       Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from "+ homeIcons +" where colID = " +id, null);
       int numFound = c.getCount();

       if(numFound<1){
           ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
           cv.put(colID, id);
           db.insert(homeIcons, colID, cv);
       }

       // else do nothing

     }

    public void DeleteHomeScreenIcon (int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(homeIcons, "id = " +id, null);
        // HELP
        //Need to  find row of homeIcons table that matches id and delete it
        db.close();
    }


}
```

You will noticed that i have 4 Logs being created.. one in the main activity' on create, one in the DataBaseManager's constructor, its onCreate, and its onUpgrade  I am using these logs to try and see when the database is created and or upgraded ect..  so far the only logs that fire are the HomeFavesActivity and the one in the constructor of the DataBaseManager.  The other two are not firing.   So how do i actually create the database, and then how do i upgrade it should i want to?

EXCEPTION ERROR:

```
03-07 12:06:33.459: D/AndroidRuntime(1257): Shutting down VM
03-07 12:06:33.459: W/dalvikvm(1257): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401df760)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sapient/com.sapient.HomeFavesActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "EXIST": syntax error
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1751)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1767)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1005)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "EXIST": syntax error
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeSql(Native Method)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:89)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1933)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1864)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at com.sapient.DataBaseManager.onCreate(DataBaseManager.java:45)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at com.sapient.HomeFavesActivity.onCreate(HomeFavesActivity.java:22)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1715)
03-07 12:06:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You will enter in those methods when you call either `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabse()` on your `DataBaseManager` instance *db*.

```
db.getWritableDatabase();
```

or

```
db.getReadableDatabase();
```

Comment: do i do that in the constructor?

Comment: @erik No, in your `HomeFavesActivity` after you create the `DataBaseManager` db object call on it `getWritableDatabase()`(`SQLiteDatabase myDatabase = db.getWritableDatabase()`). This will return your `SQLiteDatabase`(this method call will automatically call your `onCreate()` method if the database has not been created yet or `onUpgrade` if the database version are different).

Comment: I updated my code above adding db.getWritableDatabase(); to the home activity.. but it crashes now?

Comment: @erik You should also post the exception you get. Try not to close the database(`db.close()`) in the method `InsertIcons`.

Comment: I did not get any exceptions?  it just crashed

Comment: @erik If your app crashed you have an `Exception`. In the logcat view click on `All messages` on the top right corner.

Comment: i know.. it finally showed up.. something weird with the console..  anyway.. i posted the exceptions above as an edit

Comment: @erik the correct keyword in your sqlite statement in the `onCreate` method is `EXISTS` and not `EXIST` as you wrote it. Link to the documentation -> http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: @erik Change your current database version you pass on the `DatabaseManager` constructor, right now if you put `4` like you did in the code you posted then modify it, put 5 and run the app.